# Disable rememberLastLogin for Google social login

Tags: asp.net-core, google-signin

We have implemented Google social login for our net 6.0 app using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google package. All works fine, but once you've selected a google account to sign-in, if you sign-out and then choose to sign in via google, it automatically signs you in to previously selected account. How can I stop that from happening, so it asks every time?

I have looked for a property that resembles RememberLastLogin in GoogleOptions when adding google authentication, but there's nothing related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prompt the user to reauthorize your app by setting the prompt parameter to `select_account` in the authentication request. Each time your application requests authorization for an access scope, the authorization server prompts the user to select a user account.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    googleOptions.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&prompt=select_account");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

When I login：

[image]

When I click the logout button and log back in:
[image]